# Good holiday beer recipes?

Tags: beer, holiday, fruit, spices

I'm getting ready to brew up a holiday batch to bring to parties and give as gifts, etc. Any suggestions on a good one? I'm thinking a cranberry beer might be surprising and delicious...

Comment: Voted to close (subjective)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to sip a nice warming barleywine or high gravity chocolate stout.

Answer (score 1):

[The Gingerbread Man Cometh](http://hopville.com/recipe/359730/baltic-porter-recipes/the-gingerbread-man-cometh) This is my imperial spiced porter. Almost 9% ABV makes it very warming in cold weather. Spiced with ginger, nutmeg and cinnamon. Very good. Ages beautifully.